# sharepoint showing all linked items to an item in a list

Tags: sharepoint

In sharepoint 2007 , i have created three list

category

authors

books

all book belong to a author and all author belong to a category. i have done this by creating a column in authors list which has a lookup to select categories. so that while creating new item in the list author we can select category . similar thing is done in books list for authors.

i have created a web part page which displays all three list one below other.

how can i perform filtering such in this page such that if i select any category it shows all authors and books under it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use CAML to query your list. There are several samples here: [Writing CAML Queries For Retrieving List Items from a SharePoint List](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list). You'll also need to download [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://blogs.u2u.be/u2u/post/2009/11/11/New-version-of-the-U2U-CAML-Query-Builder-released.aspx) for testing proposes.